Why do I get two different answers (probability vs statistics approach)?
I am slightly confused to two concepts that I have encountered in my probability and machine learning class. Essentially the idea goes along the lines of how to best estimate the probability of an event given observations of the event. Here is an example:
Suppose we see a coin = Ber$(p)$, $p \in [0,1]$ is flipped 10 times and we see the following:
HHHHHHHHHH
We now want to figure out what $p$ is. In my probability class, I learned about the sunrise problem and its corresponding solution via rule of succession. Here we might say $p = \frac{11}{12}$.
However, from a statistics or machine learning perspective, if we want a maximum likelihood estimaton (MLE), we would say $p = 1$.
In wikipedia, it says for rule of succession: "The formula is still used, particularly to estimate underlying probabilities when there are few observations or events that have not been observed to occur at all in (finite) sample data."
while for MLE: "a method of estimating the parameters of an assumed probability distribution, given some observed data."
There seems to be some difference that I do not understand here. Why are there are two different approaches at looking at this problem? Can someone explain what is the correct way to approach the problem above? In just words, both concepts sound similar. Also, are they related to each other via a prior or something like that?

Because no one know what is the real $p$, what we can do is just to estimate it, and it is reasonable to have different values under different estimation method we use.

The maximum likelihood principle results in a point estimate that seeks to maximize the likelihood function for the unknown parameter, given the observed data.  But this is certainly not the only estimate that is possible in statistical inference, nor is it even the only type of estimate, as we often employ interval estimates to characterize the extent of uncertainty in our knowledge of the true parameter.
In your example, ten heads in ten flips is not a zero-probability outcome even when the coin is fair:  this event has probability $\frac{1}{1024}$ of occurring for a fair coin.  It is even nonzero for a coin that is biased towards tails, so long as the probability of heads $p$ for any single flip is nonzero.  Any point estimate for $p$ is precisely that, an estimate and inference based on observed data, and there is no single "correct" method of inference, only methods that are mathematically correct under certain assumptions and desired properties.
Your "rule of succession" point estimate can be derived as a Bayesian posterior predictive mean using a uniform prior on $p$.  But again, even within Bayesian inference, a uniform prior is not the only choice:  an improper prior, as the Wikipedia article you linked to explains, will give a result aligned with the MLE.
In summary, there are not simply two approaches to this problem; there are in general many ways to estimate a population parameter, and that does not make them wrong or inconsistent with each other, because parameters are unknown.  The purpose of statistics is to use observed data to make an inference about unknown quantities.  If we knew what they were, there would not be a need to estimate them.

It should be specified that the $11/12$ value is not an estimate of $p$, but rather the probability of the next flip to be head.

Your MLE-equivalent improper (Haldane) prior is uniform, but on the log-odds of Heads rather than on the probability of Heads
